# Inexplicable behaviour with method chaining

Tags: ruby

How come this works:

```
(0..5580).reduce("A") { |v, n| v = v.ord.chr }
```

But this does not:

```
eval('"A"' + ('.ord.chr' * 5580))
```

Each one is just calling `.ord` then `.chr` on "A" 5800 times. It is the exact same thing.

Comment: First of all, the latter calls `.ord` and `.chr` 5580 times both, but the former does only half of it. So there aren't equivalent

Comment: @MarekLipka cripes you're right. I have pushed a bug fix to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not exactly the same thing. The first version calls one method at a time, and returns the result to be used by the next iteration. There are only two values involved: the counter for the iteration and the current value of the reduce function.

On the other hand, the second version is interpreted as:

```
(...((("A".ord).chr).ord).chr) ... ).chr
```

To calculate the most outer method, Ruby needs to calculate the second outer parentheses; to calculate that, it needs the value returned by the third nesting; and so on. This means Ruby needs to dive 5580 parentheses deep into the stack to solve this evaluation, and Ruby needs to remember what to do on the way back once it reached the bottom. That are more intermediate steps as the Ruby stack can handle, and therefore it leads to a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` exception.

Comment: So what you say it happens during parsing. My experiment (I enclosed this long chain call - without an eval this time - in module method (without calling it), saved the file and required it in Ruby - I had the `SystemStackError` as well) confirms it.

Comment: I fell this might be correct, but I don't fully understand this. Stack is relevant for nested method calls. This case is just method chaining.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, it's not exactly the same. The first calls `chr` and `ord` alternately, with the answer being the last one computed.

The second calls them both each time, with the answer always being `chr`. Plus, that one strains ulimits<sup>1</sup> because the entire computation is compiled as a single chain.

It does go to show that there is usually a lesson in there somewhere.

---

<sup>1. We hit memory limitations so rarely these days anything seems possible, but still this is slightly crazy, as every piece of ruby needs to eat the whole thing at once, instead of just iterating over it.</sup>